# Firebase sometimes get token NULL for ios devices

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm using Ionic 3 + Cordova to develop an app. In the app, I've imported the Firebase Cloud Message library to send push notifications to android/ios users. The problem is that I've already set the certifications on Apple developer panel but sometimes the token returned by the function "get_token()" on my app is returning null only for IOS users and only sometimes. Sometimes this function returns the correctly token and then the push notifications works correctly, but sometimes not.

I've already tried remove all the certifications on the developer apple menu.

The get_token() function is in the app.component.ts file, what means that the token is generated when the user open the app.

Getting the token by the firebase server:

```
try {
      const fcmToken = await this.fcm.getToken();
      Settings.push_token = fcmToken;
}
```

Importing the library:

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';
```

This FCM variable is passed to the fcm variable inside the constructor:

```
public fcm: FCM
```

I'm hoping that the problem is on the firebase tool to get the token, because I didn't find any solution on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by calling get_token() only after platform is ready, when fcm is already connected:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => { // first, make sure platform is ready    

    this.fcm.getToken().then(token => { // save the token in the backend
```